# How to change account number onselect account type saving and current?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to change account number onselect account type saving and current?
my account type is Saving and Current and my saving account number is '123456789' and current account number '123456788' if am i selected Saving account no from dropdown then data filter from Saving if am i selected Current data showing from current

anyone can help me, please?

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import web from './../../webData.json';

const FinancialSummary = (props) => {
  const Userdetails = web.data.Home;
    const AccountDetails = web.data.Account_statement.dataList;
    const AccountType = web.data.Account_statement.dataList;
    const distintValues = _.uniqBy(AccountType, elem => [elem.Account_type, elem.Account_type].join());
    const account1 = _.uniqBy(AccountType, elem => [elem.Account_no, elem.Account_no].join());
    console.log(account1);

    const [accountType, setAccountType] = useState([]);
    const [account, setAccount] = useState([]);
    const handleAccountSelection = (event) => {
        const selectAccount = event.target.value;
        //console.log(selectAccount);
        setAccountType(account1.filter(i => i.AccountType === selectAccount));
        setAccount(account1);
    }

  return (
    <div className="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div className="marginTop20 bg1">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 borderRight1555 padd15">
            <div className="col-xl-12">
              <p className="cust_name" style={{ marginTop: '0' }}>
                {Userdetails.Name},
              </p>
              <p>
                Customer ID: <span style={{ color: '#004a8f' }}>{Userdetails.CustId}</span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 padd15">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-9">
                <p className="statementPeriod">Statement Period</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-3">
                <button type="submit" value="Save as PDF" title="" class="btn btn-primary" formtarget="_blank">
                  Save as PDF
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="clearfix"></div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <p className="marg0">From</p>
                <p className="marg0">{Userdetails.Datefrom}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-8">
                <p className="marg0">To</p>
                <p className="marg0">{Userdetails.Dateto}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="clearfix"></div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <p className="address col-md-12">{Userdetails.Address}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <div className="marginTop20">
            <p className="myAccounts">Account</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-8">
          <div className="marginTop20 bg1 padd15">
            <p className="cust_name">Expense Analysis</p>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <p>Type of account</p>
                <select id="typeOFAcc" onChange={handleAccountSelection} className="form-control">
                                  {distintValues.map((AccountDetails) => {
                                    return <option value={AccountDetails.Account_type}>{AccountDetails.Account_type}</option>;
                                  })}
                                </select>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <p>Account number</p>
                <select className="form-control">
                                    {
                                        account.map(Account_no=>{
                                            return(
                                                <option value={Account_no.Account_no}>{Account_no.Account_no}</option>
                                            )
                                        })
                                    }
                                </select>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-8"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default FinancialSummary;
```

Comment: Did you try doing the same as in `Type of account`? You would have to create a similar `handleSelect` function (with a different name of course), that calls `setAccount` instead of `setAccountType`. Then pass you handleSelect function in `onChange` in the `select` element of Àccount number`

Comment: How can you answered pls?

Comment: Based on the data you show in your question, the `web` variable is an array of objects, but you're accessing it as if it is itself an object `const Userdetails = web.data.Home`. This should throw the `web.data is undefined` error. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: no error not showing and data showing proper

Comment: It's just really hard to troubleshoot this without a reproducible example. Any chance you could get us a sandbox link?

Answer (score 1):

This example works, if I understood correctly what you need to do:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const account1 = [
  { Account_no: 0},
  { Account_no: 1},
  { Account_no: 2}
];

function App() {
  const [account, setAccount] = useState([]);
  const handleAccountSelection = (event) => {
    const selectAccount = event.target.value;
    console.log(selectAccount);
    setAccount(selectAccount);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>The selected account is: {account}</p>
      <p>Account number</p>
        <select className="form-control" onChange={ handleAccountSelection }>
          {account1.map((Account_no) => {
            return <option value={Account_no.Account_no}>{Account_no.Account_no}</option>;
          })}
        </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but my first select is account type saving and current if selection saving account then showing saving account no if selection current account then showing current ac no

Answer (score 1):

I thnk its working fine

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import web from './../../webData.json';

const FinancialSummary = (props) => {
    const Userdetails = web.data.Home;
    const AccountDetails = web.data.Account_statement.dataList;
    const AccountType = web.data.Account_statement.dataList;
    const distintValues = _.uniqBy(AccountType, elem => [elem.Account_type, elem.Account_type].join());
    const account1 = _.uniqBy(AccountType, elem => [elem.Account_no, elem.Account_no].join());
    const [account, setAccount] = useState([]);
    const handleAccountSelection = event => {
        setAccount(account1.filter(accc => accc.Account_type === event.target.value));
    };
    return(
        <div className="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div className="marginTop20 bg1">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 borderRight1555 padd15">  
                        <div className="col-xl-12">
                            <p className="cust_name" style={{marginTop: '0'}}>{Userdetails.Name},</p>
                            <p>Customer ID: <span style={{color:'#004a8f'}}>{Userdetails.CustId}</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 padd15">  
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-9">
                                <p className="statementPeriod">Statement Period</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-3">
                                <button type="submit"  value="Save as PDF" title="" className="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Save as PDF</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="clearfix"></div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                <p className="marg0">From</p>
                                <p className="marg0">{Userdetails.Datefrom}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-8">
                                <p className="marg0">To</p>
                                <p className="marg0">{Userdetails.Dateto}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="clearfix"></div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <p className="address col-md-12">{Userdetails.Address}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="marginTop20">
                        <p className="myAccounts">Account</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-8">
                    <div className="marginTop20 bg1 padd15">
                        <p className="cust_name">Expense Analysis</p>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                <p>Type of account</p>
                                <select className="form-control" onChange={handleAccountSelection}>
                                    {distintValues.map(Account_no => {
                                      return (
                                        <option key={Account_no.id} value={Account_no.Account_type}>
                                          {Account_no.Account_type}
                                        </option>
                                      );
                                    })}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                <p>Account number</p>
                                <select id="accno" className="form-control" required>
                                    <option value="">Select Account no</option>
                                    {account.map(Account_no => {
                                      return (
                                        <option key={Account_no.id} value={Account_no.Account_no}>
                                          {Account_no.Account_no}
                                        </option>
                                      );
                                    })}
                                  </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">View</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-8">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default FinancialSummary
```

filter here solution

```
const handleAccountSelection = event => {
    setAccount(account1.filter(accc => accc.Account_type === event.target.value));
 };
    
    <select id="accno" className="form-control" required>
        <option value="">Select Account no</option>
          {account.map(Account_no => {
            return (
                <option key={Account_no.id} value={Account_no.Account_no}>
                  {Account_no.Account_no}
                </option>
            );
        })}
    </select>
```